# Identifying clickable element in angularjs - ng-binding

Tags: angularjs, automation, protractor

I have a search field with results powered by ElasticSearch and I am automating the selecting of one of the results. CSS and XPath do not yield very much in terms of selecting the element and clicking it so I am hoping for some help.

**Code:**

```
li data-ng-repeat="match in matches" data-ng-class="{active:          isActive($index) }" data-ng-mouseenter="selectActive($index)" data-ng-  click="selectMatch($index)" class="ng-scope active">
<a tabindex="-1" class="bg-info ng-scope">
<div class="search-item-container row">
<div class="col-sm-10">
  <span class="company-name ng-binding" bind-html-unsafe="match.model.name.length > 30 ? (match.model.name.substr(0,30) + '...').toLowerCase() : match.model.name.toLowerCase() | typeaheadHighlight:query"><strong>alph</strong>, incorporated</span>
  <div class="company-info">
    <address>
      <span class="address-span-container ng-isolate-scope" data-ng-switch="displayFormat" data-obb-address-display-directive="" data-addresses="match.model.addresses" data-display-format="inlineCsz"
```

Using Protractor my selector would be:
`element(by."some selector"(item to select))).click();`

I've tried both CSS and Xpath and the results are:
  `NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.cssSelector(".search-popup li:nth-child(3) a")`

Comment: Could you provide us with some more of the HTML code? This will allow us to provide you with an accurate answer.

Comment: I've tried to add some more code but it won't work for me (I'm guessing because I'm doing something wrong). So the jist is this, if you go to https://openbookben.com/ and enter a name like "acme" or any company name really, the search dropdown appears and I am trying to select a company from that dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [openbookben.com](https://openbookben.com), it looks like you need the following steps:

1. Send your search query to the appropriate element (`sendKeys` to the `#landingSearch` element)
2. Let Protractor wait until the search results become displayed. This is the case when the `element(by.css(ul.dropdown-menu)).isDisplayed()` promise yields true.
3. Click on one of the search results from the `match in matches` repeater using, e.g., Protractor's `all.elements(by.repeater('match in matches'))`
4. Again, let Protractor wait, this time until the new page with `company` in the URL is loaded.

For the waiting in steps 2 and 4, you can use Protractor's [wait](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) method, or Protractor's [Expected Conditions](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions).

Your `NoSuchElementError` occurs because without the waiting, the search results are not there yet.

Comment: I'm still not clear on step 3. 'match in matches'. If I click one of the results, the new page loads which is good. But I am not sure how the selector works. How do I actually get Protractor to actually pick .click() a particular result? All of the results have the 'match in matches' so I'm not sure how to discern which I'm actually selecting?

Comment: Okay think I've got it figured out. This can be closed. Thanks everyone!